# Simple content swapper with next/prev button

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have a list on my page where each *li* represent a different content block.

I want only one visible block. The *li* with the class 'visible' is the one to show.

When I click on the next button, I want the visible class to move to the next *li*. Same for the previous button.

And when we reach the end, I want it to start again from the beginning. Same if you hit "Prev" on the first one, it should go to the last one.

Iam beginning in jquery, so I need help!

HTML structure

```
<ul class="container">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" class="prev">prev</button>
<button type="button" class="next">next</button>
```

CSS

```
.container li { display:none; }
.container li.visible { display:block; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container li:first-child').addClass('visible');
});

var numberOfItems =  $('.container li').size();

$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.container').find('.visible').removeClass('visible').next().addClass('visible');
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('.container').find('.visible').removeClass('visible').prev().addClass('visible');
});
```

I'm stuck there! I feel that this code is not really good, and I need the 'circular' functionality. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [How to swap visible list item using next and previous buttons?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-swap-visible-list-item-using-next-and-previous-buttons/) link, this will help you to get the required answer. When you click on the next button, the visible class will move to the next li, this is same for the previous button. And if it reach the end, it will start again from the beginning, similarly for the Prev button.
//For Next

```
 if (index == (length - 1)) {
            $('li').first().removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');
        }
```

//For Prev

```
if (index == 0) {
        $('li').last().removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');
    }
```

i hope this will you more. all the best.